# Putting two plots in a manipulate whilst keeping the plots visible

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to look at both the real and imaginary parts of some functions that depend on a parameter n. Individually (with set values of n), I get perfectly nice graphs, but when putting them in a Manipulate they become very small.

Here is the exact code I'm using; remove the manipulate and the graphs display at a good size, but with it they are too small to be legible.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Im[Sqrt[-1 + (x + I y)^2 n]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic]
  Plot3D[Re[Sqrt[-1 + (x + I y)^2 n]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic]
 , {n, 1, 10, 1}]
```

Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: In this code you are multiplying two plots. Never a good idea. Could make a list of them ,y adding the {} and a comma.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, it is amazing to me how common that error is even in my code. Even after wrapping them in `{ }`, I'll still forget to separate the terms by a comma. It can be a frustrating bug to track down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Plot3D[Im[Sqrt[-1 + (x + I y)^2 n]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, 
          AxesLabel -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300] , 
   Plot3D[Re[Sqrt[-1 + (x + I y)^2 n]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
          AxesLabel -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300]}], 
{n, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Remember that you may also do something like:

```
a = Sequence @@{{x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, AxesLabel-> Automatic, ImageSize-> 200};
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Plot3D[Im[Sqrt[-1 + (x + I y)^2 n]], Evaluate@a],
   Plot3D[Re[Sqrt[-1 + (x + I y)^2 n]], Evaluate@a]}],
 {n, 1, 10, 1}, 
 PreserveImageOptions -> False]
```

Comment: The "ImageSize -> 300" was enough. Thankyou!

Comment: @belisarius `Row` requires `List` as the first argument. It explains why it remains unevaluated on your screenshot.

Comment: @Alexey Thanks. I didn't notice (I was playing with several alternatives, and finally chose this one). Editing

Comment: @belisarius For what `PreserveImageOptions -> False` is needed in your **Edit** section?

Comment: @Alexey I found that without specifying it, when you rerun the code in a cell with the plots from the previous run already present, sometimes the new plots "inherit" parameters from the last actions you made over the old plots, so it is difficult to detect what is the "clean" display for your new parameters. That is solved by "PreserveImageOptions -> False"

Comment: @Sjoerd It's not yet there, but will be among belisarius's badges tomorrow. It is a gold badge for Mathematica tag, the first ever. As of yesterday, I was 4 questions short of it, and belisarius - 10 or something upvotes. As of now, I am still 3 questions short, while belisarius just got all it takes to get it. Should have it awarded to him tonight, but why not start celebrating now?